# ASP.NET EntityFramework не могу получить записи через навигационное свойство

Tags: c#, asp.net

Вот код модели:

```
public class Lection
{
    [Key]
    public int LectionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SubText { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
    public string OtherAutors { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Lecturer> Owners { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }

    public Lection()
    {
        Chapters = new List<Chapter>();
        Owners = new List<Lecturer>();
        Links = new List<Link>();
    }
}

public class Chapter
{
    [Key]
    public int ChapterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SubText { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int LectionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LectionId")]
    public Lection Lection { get; set; }
}
```

Отсюда видно, что БД нормально заполняется тестовыми данными. [image: Скриншот]

Но при этом такой код:

```
  @foreach (var c in ViewBag.Lection.Chapters)
                {
                    <h2 class="ChapterTitle"><a name="@c.Name">@c.Name</a></h2>
                    <div class="ChapterSub">@c.SubText</div>
                    <p>@c.Text</p>
                }
```

не выводит ничего.
Ну и код контроллера на всякий случай:

```
if ((ViewBag.Lection = db.Lections.Find(id)) == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        return View();
```

Подскажите, кто в этом разбирается, ибо сил уже просто нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы у Вас работали навигационные свойства, они должны быть помечены как `virtual`, т.к. EF для того что механизм навигационных свойств работал, переопределяет их.

```
public class Lection
{
    [Key]
    public int LectionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SubText { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
    public string OtherAutors { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Lecturer> Owners { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Link> Links { get; set; }

    public Lection()
    {
       Chapters = new List<Chapter>();
       Owners = new List<Lecturer>();
       Links = new List<Link>();
    }
}

public class Chapter
{
    [Key]
    public int ChapterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SubText { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int LectionId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LectionId")]
    public virtual Lection Lection { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Господи... Спасибо вам огромное ) После Java в упор этого virtual не замечаю, даже обидно сколько времени убил из-за невнимательности.